# Get week and year before or after specific number of weeks in PHP

Tags: php

I have a week number and its year (e.g. week:2, year:2022) and I am trying to find a way to calculate the week number and the relative year if a specific number of weeks is subtracted or added.

I am trying to find a solution like

```
$three_weeks_ago = date("W", strtotime("-3 week"));
```

but this one is based on the current date and goes 3 week before now.
I want 3 weeks before a specific given combination of week and year.

Comment: Could you give example of input and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

strtotime takes an additional optional parameter for relative timestamps called $baseTimestamp. (See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

I believe this is what you're after:

```php
<?php
$week = 2;
$year = 2022;
$amount_of_weeks_ago = 3;

$past_date = strtotime($year."W".sprintf("%02u", $week)); // Need to prepend week with a 0 if it's less than 10
$timestamp_three_weeks_ago = strtotime("-{$amount_of_weeks_ago} week", $past_date);
$timestamp_three_weeks_ago_as_string = date("Y-m-d W", $timestamp_three_weeks_ago);

var_dump($timestamp_three_weeks_ago_as_string); // 2021-12-20 51
```